# add modifier to png image?

Tags: image

Im following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bF3O4qbaMqs
which explains how to curve and animate text. But I've designed my text in gimp and imported it as a png file into blender. The video goes on to use the object modifier tab which isn't available for the png file, what can I do?

Many thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a "png" file inside Blender. It was either imported as a an empty or as a plane. The former is useless for modeling and rendering purposes, the second can also have modifiers, but don't expect the versatility of an actual model

Comment: What do you mean by "which isn't available"? Every mesh has availability of modifier stack, that is in Properties section

Answer (score 4):

As you have read from the other answers this is not a good way to do this. I would use actual 3D text like they did in the tutorial you posted.

However to give your question an answer.

[image]

1. Import image as planes (choose your text PNG)
2. Make sure you subdivide your text plane to give it more geometry to bend.
3. Make an Empty and leave it in the center of your text.
4. on your text/image object add the simple deform modifier and choose the empty as the object to bend around.

Keep in mind you are very limited this way because you are using a picture of text and not actual text.

Answer (score 1):

Blender is for 3D, not for working with images.
What you are trying to do is possible but not recommended. Just dragging an image into blender imports it as a background image, this feature is meant to be used for reference images. These images aren't actually objects. You can use the import images as planes addon to import your png as a plane. Then you can subdivide it and apply the modifier as shown. But I wouldn't recommend this as you won't be able to add thickness to the text and you could be running into problems with transparency (it's just an image after all) Just using a text object is way easier and gives you much better results anyway.